# Is non-linearity added to neural networks because of its derivatives?

Tags: neural-network, sigmoid

I have question:
I always assumed that non-linearity was applied to a neural-network in order to calculate the minimum of a error surface.
If the function is f(x)=mx+b the derivative is always f'(x) = 1.

Is this one of the reasons why non-linearity ( exempli gratia through sigmoid functions which derivative is f'(x)=f(x)*(1-f(x))) is applied?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The neural network is a model of your problem, making predictions
for inputs. The loss function is a measure of the accuracy of
predictions with respect to the observed results.
"Linearity" typically refers to the model. A linear model is a very
simple one: many interesting problems can be approximated by linear
functions, but often you need a more sophisticated model.
Since the sequential composition of linear functions is still linear,
the expressiveness of deep networks derives from the fact of inserting
non linear activation functions modulating the output of artificial
neurons (approximating a thresholding filter). These non linear functions
must be derivable to work with the backpropagation algorithm.
Indipendently from the model, the loss function can be "linear" (L1),
such as the sum of absolute deviations, or non linear, such as
mean squared residuals (L2) or other different loss functions. Again,
the loss function must be derivable too.

See for instance this [lecture](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec3.pdf) by Hinton et al. 
for the discussion of a simple linear model with a L2 loss function
(then enriched with a sigmoid activation function).